# Typescript: Is there a type for numerable?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I would like to know if there is a type for numerable data.
To me numerable is a number or a string that can be converted into a number for exemple:

```
const a = 1; // it's a numerable
const b = "1"; // it's a numerable since typeof +b === 'number '
const c = "zerezre" // it's not a numerable
```

at the beginning I was trying to create my own type

```
export type Numerable = number | string;
```

but this was not explicite and a lot of error can appear.
So I was thinking of creating validator with phantom type but this is not really what I want (I guess) since I only want to defined type and not add check inside the running program.

Can someone have any idea ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: No I would like a type, not a check in the run time. (If it's possible of course)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to use the [template literal string types introduced in TypeScript 4.1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html) to accomplish this:

```
type Numerable = number | `${number}`
```

All of your examples work as expected - [see here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcgrgWwgJwIYCMA20C8UB2i6KUAPlAAYAkA3oQscgL4UBQrAxgPb4DOwUVFABcsRCgzYoeAIwBuKAHpFUAJbAA5L0EFxaLBE49+UdCLFJ9UvACIZNhcrWbtQ+hINReq-B2ihILgAzKABqMxxIqA16RmijPgEOc3hLSVwoGwAvFAgs5AgbJRV1LQIuATc9dKA).

Comment: And if we want only integers, we could also use  `````${bigint}`````

Comment: Yea really cool thanks a lot.

Important to mention that it doesn't work with typescript version below 4.1

But it will what I want thanks ! :)

Comment: It's called [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html).